# Magento 2 - Custom admin theme not working in production mode

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, theme, static-content

I create a custom admin theme to override few admin template files. In developer mode theme work perfect, but when I turn on production mode and make: `bin/magento setup: static-content: deploy` then: `bin/magento cache: flash` theme not work. In DB theme is registered. When I check pub/static/adminhtml/custom_module/custom_module there are no files.

Comment: Admin theme is not working yet, you have to overrider admin files you have to create module and overrider core files of adminpanel.

Comment: Yes, I do that, I override admin template files in `app/design/adminhtml/custommodule/customodule`. In developer mode everything is ok, but when I turn production mode magento won't compile/merge my custom admin theme with Magento/backend theme.

Comment: My admin panel in production mode look like this: https://postimg.org/image/co0ipu0vl

Comment: I found solution: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3754

Comment: How to solve @MarekKarmelski?