# Magento 2: Overiding Admin Theme not working in Production Mode with CDN [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, deploy, cdn

[Magento 2: How to enable newly created admin theme & override module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148516/magento-2-how-to-enable-newly-created-admin-theme-override-module)

After achieving this I have a new issue now.

I'm using CDN & in Production Mode. In the Developer mode, it works fine.

I have below configuration in Admin

**Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer**

```
1] JavaScript Settings
    Merge JavaScript Files -> Yes
    Enable JavaScript Bundling -> Yes
    Minify JavaScript Files -> Yes

2] CSS Settings
    Merge CSS Files -> Yes
    Minify CSS Files -> Yes
```

**Developer Mode:**

https://cdn.domain.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Alphanova/Theme/en_US/requirejs/require.js

https://cdn.domain.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Alphanova/Theme/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js

**Production Mode:**

https://cdn.domain.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Alphanova/Theme/en_US/requirejs/require.min.js

Admin is not working due to JS not loading. Above are just a few JS files.

https://cdn.domain.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Alphanova/Theme/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js

In Production Mode I'm not able to locate the file on above location.

```
magento/pub/static/adminhtml/Custom/Theme/em_US // ALL FILES SHOULD BE HERE
magento/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US // ALL FILES STAYS HERE
```

[Magento 2 - Custom admin theme not working in production mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142735/magento-2-custom-admin-theme-not-working-in-production-mode)

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the changes needs to apply

**magento\app\design\adminhtml\Custom\Theme\theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My Theme Tile</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent> 
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

I added below files & solved.

```
 magento\app\design\adminhtml\Custom\Theme\media\preview.png
 magento\app\design\adminhtml\Custom\Theme\web\images\logo.png
```

Answer (score 3):

When creating a new custom theme, **if we don't have any assets files under `web` folder, your theme may be ignored when executing deploy command**.

Comment: Thats the trick, you save my day..!

Comment: This should be fixed since 2.1.10 (Issue #7569) but this happened to me on 2.3.7 on the theme that had a web folder that only contained directories.

Answer (score 0):

I installed cdn, but my images no longer appear on the site, and I also can not correctly access my admin panel. How can I reverse the cdn settings?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this Run the following command from Magento Root

```
rm -r generated/*/*
```

Then

php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:flush && php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile && php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US && php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:clean